# What is the correct URL to use for GET requests to another Kubernetes container?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I'm trying to create a simple microservice, where a JQuery app in one Docker container uses this code to get a JSON object from another (analytics) app that runs in a different container:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#get-info-btn').click(function(){
  $.get("http://localhost:8084/productinfo", 
  function(data, status){          
    $.each(data, function(i, obj) {
      //some code
    });   
  });
});
});
</script>
```

The other app uses this for the `Deployment` containerPort.

```
  ports:
    - containerPort: 8082
```

and these for the `Service` ports.

```
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - targetPort: 8082
      port: 8084
```

The 'analytics' app is a golang program that listens on 8082.

```
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/productinfo", getInfoJSON)    
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8082", nil))
}
```

When running this on Minikube, I encountered issues with CORS, which was resolved by using this in the golang code when returning a JSON object as a response:

```
w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type")
```

All this worked fine on Minikube (though in Minikube I was using `localhost:8082`). The first app would send a GET request to `http://localhost:8084/productinfo` and the second app would return a JSON object.

But when I tried it on a cloud Kubernetes setup by accessing the first app via :, when I open the browser console, I keep getting the error `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8084/productinfo`.

**Question:**
Why is it working on Minikube but not on the cloud Kubernetes worker nodes? Is using `localhost` the right way to access another container? How can I get this to work? How do people who implement microservices use their GET and POST requests across containers? All the microservice examples I found are built for simple demos on Minikube, so it's difficult to get a handle on this nuance.

Comment: typically, using services, if within the cluster then using `clusterIP`'s DNS name(without port).

Comment: Thank you. I've tried looking at a lot of Kubernetes tutorials and the official docs about how to use this DNS name, but it isn't clear to me yet. Would be great if you could elaborate. I've noticed that most tutorials do not try seeing it from the perspective of someone who is totally new to Kubernetes.

Comment: Check out ingress,

Comment: @P....: Matt helped figure out the problem. It was a typo in the manifest file. As for the JQuery, I guess the request didn't go through because it was issued from the client side, and it wasn't part of the container.

Comment: Glad you got your answer. Sorry couldn't help much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@P.... is absolutely right, I just want to provide some more details about [DNS for Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/) and communication between containers in the same Pod.

##### DNS for Services

As we can find in the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#services), Kubernetes Services are assigned a DNS A (or AAAA) record, for a name of the form `<serviceName>.<namespaceName>.svc.<cluster-domain>`. This resolves to the cluster IP of the Service.

> "Normal" (not headless) Services are assigned a DNS A or AAAA record, depending on the IP family of the service, for a name of the form my-svc.my-namespace.svc.cluster-domain.example. This resolves to the cluster IP of the Service.

Let's break down the form `<serviceName>.<namespaceName>.svc.<cluster-domain>` into individual parts:

- `<serviceName>` - The name of the Service you want to connect to.
- `<namespaceName>` - The name of the Namespace in which the Service to which you want to connect resides.
- `svc` - This should not be changed - `svc` stands for Service.
- `<cluster-domain>` - cluster domain, by default it's `cluster.local`.

We can use `<serviceName>` to access a Service in the same Namespace, however we can also use `<serviceName>.<namespaceName>` or `<serviceName>.<namespaceName>.svc` or FQDN `<serviceName>.<namespaceName>.svc.<cluster-domain>`.

If the Service is in a different Namespace, a single `<serviceName>` is not enough and we need to use  `<serviceName>.<namespaceName>` (we can also use: `<serviceName>.<namespaceName>.svc` or `<serviceName>.<namespaceName>.svc.<cluster-domain>`).

In the following example, `app-1` and `app-2` are in the same Namespace and `app-2` is exposed with ClusterIP on port `8084` (as in your case):

```
$ kubectl run app-1 --image=nginx
pod/app-1 created

$ kubectl run app-2 --image=nginx
pod/app-2 created

$ kubectl expose pod app-2 --target-port=80 --port=8084
service/app-2 exposed

$ kubectl get pod,svc
NAME        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/app-1   1/1     Running   0          45s
pod/app-2   1/1     Running   0          41s

NAME                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
service/app-2        ClusterIP   10.8.12.83   <none>        8084/TCP   36s
```

**NOTE:** The `app-2` is in the same Namespace as `app-1`, so we can use  `<serviceName>` to access it from `app-1`, you can also notice that we got the FQDN for `app-2` (`app-2.default.svc.cluster.local`):

```
$ kubectl exec -it app-1 -- bash
root@app-1:/# nslookup app-2
Server:         10.8.0.10
Address:        10.8.0.10#53

Name:   app-2.default.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.8.12.83
```

**NOTE:** We need to provide the port number because `app-2` is listening on `8084`:

```
root@app-1:/# curl app-2.default.svc.cluster.local:8084
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
...
```

Let's create `app-3` in a different Namespace and see how to connect to it from `app-1`:

```
$ kubectl create ns test-namespace
namespace/test-namespace created

$ kubectl run app-3 --image=nginx -n test-namespace
pod/app-3 created

$ kubectl expose pod app-3 --target-port=80 --port=8084 -n test-namespace
service/app-3 exposed
```

**NOTE:** Using `app-3` (`<serviceName>`) is not enough, we also need to provide the name of the Namespace in which `app-3` resides (`<serviceName>.<namespaceName>`):

```
# nslookup app-3
Server:         10.8.0.10
Address:        10.8.0.10#53

** server can't find app-3: NXDOMAIN

# nslookup app-3.test-namespace
Server:         10.8.0.10
Address:        10.8.0.10#53

Name:   app-3.test-namespace.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.8.12.250

# curl app-3.test-namespace.svc.cluster.local:8084
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
...
```

##### Communication Between Containers in the Same Pod

We can use `localhost` to communicate with other containers, but **only** within the same Pod (Multi-container pods).

I've created a simple multi-container Pod with two containers: `nginx-container` and `alpine-container`:

```
$ cat multi-container-app.yml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: multi-container-app
spec:
  containers:
  - image: nginx
    name: nginx-container
  - image: alpine
    name: alpine-container
    command: ["sleep", "3600"]

$ kubectl apply -f multi-container-app.yml
pod/multi-container-app created
```

We can connect to the `alpine-container` container and check if we can access the nginx web server located in the `nginx-container` with `localhost`:

```
$ kubectl exec -it multi-container-app -c alpine-container -- sh

/ # netstat -tulpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      -

/ # curl localhost
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
...
```

More information on communication between containers in the same Pod can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67061603/how-to-communicate-between-containers-in-same-pod-in-kubernetes).

Comment: Thank you, but even after adding the port number, I'm getting a name not resolved error in the browser console. `GET http://analytics-svc:8084/productinfo net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`

Comment: What do you mean by `browser console`. Using `ClusterIP` makes the Service only reachable from within the cluster.
How are you trying to connect ?

Comment: I'm running the apps on a Linode LKE cluster. So I can access frontend app's `index.html` using `http://<nodeIP>:<nodePort>/`. So `index.html` gets rendered on my browser and when I press `F12`, the browser console opens up. In the Kubernetes folder you'll see that the frontend app is a `LoadBalancer`. Ah...you meant that I won't be able to access analytics from the browser console.

Comment: To access the service from the container, I created a new auth Flask app (please see the new commits into the repository) that uses requests.get('http://analytics-svc:8084/productinfo').content. But now I get a connection error: Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fcb5c722790>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused')). analytics-svc is getting resolved to the correct IP address. Just can't figure out what's going wrong! Please help.

Comment: @Nav There are several issues (`ports` & `selector`) with your `analytics.yml` file.
I've corrected it, please check [analytics.yml](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/matt-j-so/kubernetes-manifests/main/analytics.yml).
I ran `curl analytics-svc:8084/productinfo` from the `auth-flask` Pod and got this response: `[{"productname":"Bread","cost":"$2.33"},{"productname":"Butter","cost":"$1.66"},{"productname":"Jam","cost":"$6"},{"productname":"Ketchup","cost":"$2.4"}]`.

Comment: Gaah!!! A typo cost me so many days? Thanks a million Matt!!! Right from the beginning, I was thinking that not having referential integrity of the port numbers and entity names was a major mistake the Google engineers made. I was right. I wonder how many hours of productivity people would've lost worldwide because of these tiny errors. After so many decades of building the internet, our engineers are still not creating simple, error-free interfaces.

Comment: @matt_j your answer is clearly showing efforts and time.  you should consider such answers not in community rather your own. Great work.